# Kibana unexpectedly changed timeFieldName

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

We've faced with a problem when Kibana unexpectedly changed timeFieldName for a index-pattern. As far as we know no one changed it.
But:
Was:

```
-bash-4.1$ curl "http://localhost:9200/.kibana/index-pattern/logstash-*?pretty"
{
  "_index" : ".kibana",
  "_type" : "index-pattern",
  "_id" : "logstash-*",
  "_version" : 2277,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "title" : "logstash-*",
    "timeFieldName" : "@timestamp",
    "fields" : "<some>"
  }
}
```

After some time:

```
-bash-4.1$ curl "http://localhost:9200/.kibana/index-pattern/logstash-*?pretty"
{
  "_index" : ".kibana",
  "_type" : "index-pattern",
  "_id" : "logstash-*",
  "_version" : 2283,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "title" : "logstash-*",
    "timeFieldName" : "received_at",
```

So the question is - what could cause this changes ? Or how to detect it ?
Thanks in advice.

Comment: What're the indexes you're having in `Kibana`?

Comment: Just logstash-<date>.
We blame broken logstash configuration that caused pattern change.

Comment: Are you running any logstash conf, which contains timestamp matching?

Comment: It's hard to say, as we run a lot of logstash clients .....
For now it's mystically changed back to recieved_at field and seems stable ...